# Etymology of words "throw" and "catch" when talking about "programming exceptions"

Tags: etymology, programming

*I must first apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this.  According to the guidelines on cs.stackexchange and stackoverflow, this question was clearly considered "off topic" for both of those networks. It's frequently unclear where some questions should be posted.*

In Oracle's [documentation for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html), they state:

> When an error occurs within a method, the method creates an object and
>   hands it off to the runtime system. ... Creating an
>   exception object and handing it to the runtime system is called
>   throwing an exception.

Given the explanation from these docs, I might imagine a more direct and unimaginative word choice would have been something like "hand" and "receive" (since the Exception is "handed" off to the runtime).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#In_software) says *"One mechanism to transfer control, or raise an exception, is known as a throw"*, which brings me to my point: raising makes sense because it is idiomatic English, in the same vein as "raising an issue during a meeting" but throw doesn't really apply to exceptions, issues, or errors outside of computer science.

Since a lot of jargon in CS comes from analogy to similar non-CS ideas (buses, bridges, masks, etc...), I've always wondered this: **what analogy or thinking informed the use of the words "throw" and "catch" relating to exceptions and errors?**

Thank you.

Comment: They had to pick some sort of terms.  The metaphor of "throw" and "catch" fits pretty well, at least to anyone familiar with American baseball.

Comment: It is idiomatic to **catch** an error anyway. Also The Oxford Dictionary has for [**catch**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/catch): Come upon (someone) unexpectedly. *‘unexpected snow caught us by surprise’* and other similar uses.

Comment: @WeatherVane - But, oddly, you can only "catch" an exception in most programming languages if you're expecting it.

Comment: An attestation of  "threw an error" from *The Electrical World and Engineer*. New York, 1900. https://books.google.com/books?id=_FNEAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA663&dq=%22threw+an+error%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij88OJqIvhAhUMMd8KHSMPBCIQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22threw%20an%20error%22&f=false

Comment: And here's one of "throws an error":  *Productive Dairying*. Philadelphia, 1917. https://books.google.com/books?id=p-AqAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA323&dq=%22throws+an+error%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAzMWDqYvhAhVrmeAKHVGXC68Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22throws%20an%20error%22&f=false

Comment: And here's one of "throws errors": *Techniques of Plant Maintenance and Engineering*.  Madison Wisconsin, 1950. https://books.google.com/books?id=DDbSAAAAMAAJ&q=%22throw+errors%22&dq=%22throw+errors%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjox6KoqovhAhVpdt8KHeYWBfcQ6AEIVzAJ

Comment: Great references, thank you, all!